# Does anyone have a way to delete id before passing through url? React Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

Does anyone have a way to delete id before passing through url?
I want to remove the id that is in the addedItems array.

### Delete only id. Without interfering with the value inside

```
 onFinish = async(values) => {
    const { addedItems, total } = this.state;
    values.re_total = total;
    const { data, result } = this.props.loginReducer;
    await addedItems.forEach((doc) => {
      doc.car_number = values.cus_car_number;
      doc.reference = values.re_reference;
      doc.detail = values.re_detail;
      doc.adName = result.data.u_fname;
      doc.total = doc.price * doc.quantity;
    });
    delete addedItems.id;
    console.log(addedItems)
    await httpClient
            .post(`http://localhost:8085/api/v1/revenue/revenue`,{addedItems})
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Error :", error);
            })
    message.success({ content: 'บันทึกรายรับเรียบร้อย!', duration: 2, style: {
      marginTop: '5vh',
    }} ,100);
    await this.props.history.goBack();
  };
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what is in the `addedItems` array and the values being passed into the `onFinish` function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the id is in each item of the addedItems array. Rather than it being added to the array directly (`addedItems.id = 'bad'`).

I switched from using a `Array#forEach` to `Array#map` so that it creates a new array. Then I use object destructuring with the rest operator (`...`). So I can pull the id out of the doc object and make a shallow copy of the doc at the same time. The shallow copy is important so we don't accidentally modify state values without meaning to.

That's actually the biggest issue in your code as is - it's modifying the `this.state.addedItems` unintentionally, as you are changing the docs without doing a shallow copy first.

As for the code: Replace the `await addedItems.forEach()` with this. You didn't actually need an await there, as `Array#forEach` doesn't return anything let alone a promise.

```
const mappedItems = addedItems.map(({id,...doc})=>{
      doc.car_number = values.cus_car_number;
      doc.reference = values.re_reference;
      doc.detail = values.re_detail;
      doc.adName = result.data.u_fname;
  return doc;
})
```

Then use `{addedItems: mappedItems}` as the body of the `httpClient.post`. So that you use the new array instead of the old one pulled from the state.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice given to beginners.